# Connect to Redshift Serverless across accounts

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

I have account A with AWS Redshift Serverless namespace and workgroup.
The workgroup is not public accessable.
I want to connect from AWS account B to the namespace on account A.
How is that possible?
I found this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-cluster-cross-vpc.html), but it supports only Clusters.

Is there a way to do cross-account connections on Redshift Serverless?

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I took to implement cross-account access to Redshift Serverless.
Suppose you will use Lambda function to access Redshift Serverless from different account.

• ***Account A wants to connect to Redshift serverless***

• ***Account B is the account with Redshift Serverless***

1. Create a ***VPC Peering*** connection between **Account A** and **B** *[manage routes in both ways]*
2. **Manage Security Groups**
   • For Lambda function in account A, add inbound rule on `port TCP 5439` and choose `Redshift Serverless SG` as `source`.
   • Do the same with `Redhsift Serveless SG` and as `source` add `Lambda SG`.*[It will automatically add the account ID in fronf of SG]*
3. In ***Account A***, in `Lambda execution role` add `Policy` to assume IAM Role from account B, that has access to Redshift Serverless.
4. In ***account B***, for the IAM Role edit `Trust Policy` to add `arn` from Lambda `Execution Policy` from account A.

The Policy examples and more detailed explamation is available on link: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role#

Now, write the Lambda code and test the connection. Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Unlike Redshift Clustered, AWS does not provide a built-in way to create VPC endpoint access for Redshift Serverless in a different AWS account. You'd have to resort to something like a VPC Peering to achieve this.